# Elegant way to check if JQuery object has an event under a namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

For Instance, lets say we want to check if `this` has any events under the namespace proxy; I currently do:

```
// 'this' is not a DOM element
if ($($(this).data('events')).length === 0 || $($(this).data('events').proxy).length === 0) {
    // Do something If there are no events
}
```

This is how I do it now in order to assure that the `.data('events')` object has been created (if there has not been a .bind called prior to reading `.data('events')` it will be undefined) AND it has an event under the `proxy` namespace.

Is there a better way to do this without throwing an error?  It'd be great **if** I could do something like:

```
if($(this).data('events').proxy.length === 0) {
    // Do something if there are no proxy events
}
```

**However**, if there has not been anything bound to `this` the code snippet will throw an error because `.data('events')` will be undefined and therefore will not have a `.proxy` accessor.

Comment: Also, `.data("events")` has been moved in newer versions of jQuery and it is suggested to not use it. Though, i'm not sure of an alternative.

Comment: Note that in 1.8 `data('events')` has disappeared. You now need `$._data(this[0], 'events')`.

Comment: And jQuery team recommend not to use it because "the actual data structures may change incompatibly from version to version" as we can read it here : http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just beef up the truthiness checks accordingly:

```
var data_events = $(this).data('events');
if(!data_events || data_events.proxy.length === 0) {
    // Do something if there are no proxy events
}
```